# unable to import from a package in the same directory

Tags: python

I have a python package with the following structure:

```
mypackage/
 |______   bar
 |______  __iniit__.py
install.py
```

**init**.py has:

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)


from ._version import get_versions
__version__ = get_versions()['version']
del get_versions
```

In install.py when I do

```
from mypackage.bar import config
```

I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmp0wXmB4/install.py", line 366, in <module>
    from mypackage.bar import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mypackage/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._version import get_versions
```

I tried doing `del mypackage.bar` after importing but it doesn't work. Any pointers to what could be missing?

Comment: You showed the traceback but not the error message.  Show the error message.

Comment: The only error I get is `ImportError: cannot import name get_versions`

Comment: What does your generated `_version.py` contain?  Post the whole contents in the question.